Normalising data in dat file with sections into a pandas dataframe
I have a file that show an example of a data as below
CAR REPORT                                  AREA 1                                                                                                                                
               Car  Honda              Country  America                        
                  Type  Car                                  
                 Built. location  Japan             Ship. location China                       
                 Date  2023/01/02        transport  shipping                                                   
                                                                               
============================================================================================================================
 PPM         Price   Age
============================================================================================================================
   2,000     100     12
   3,000     100     13
   3,000     100     13
   3,000     100     13
   3,000     100     13




CAR REPORT                                  AREA 2                                                                                                                                
               Car  Toyota              Country  America                        
                  Type  Car                                
                 Built. location  Japan             Ship. location China                       
                 Date  2023/01/02        transport  shipping                                                
                                                                     
============================================================================================================================
 PPM         Price   Age
============================================================================================================================
   2,000     100     12
   3,000     100     13
   3,000     100     13
   3,000     100     13
   3,000     100     13

Im trying to write a script in pandas/python so that I can produce a dataframe as the below
I tried to do an open file via python and read line by line and what I did was to do a regex to put the subsections like the header portions into a separate dataframe and then perform a merge back. It works but its a little inefficient.
I wonder is there any ready pandas functions which I can leverage instead of looping over the file as there are multiple sections involved and multiple files.
CAR | COUNTRY | TYPE | Built.Location | ship.Location | Date | Transport | PPM | Price| Age
Honda| America | Car | Japan | China | 2023/01/02 | shipping | 2,000 | 100| 12
Honda| America | Car | Japan | China | 2023/01/02 | shipping | 3,000 | 100| 13
Honda| America | Car | Japan | China | 2023/01/02 | shipping | 3,000 | 100| 13
Honda| America | Car | Japan | China | 2023/01/02 | shipping | 3,000 | 100| 13
Honda| America | Car | Japan | China | 2023/01/02 | shipping | 3,000 | 100| 13
Toyota| America | Car | Japan | China | 2023/01/02 | shipping | 2,000 | 100| 12
Toyota| America | Car | Japan | China | 2023/01/02 | shipping | 3,000 | 100| 13
Toyota| America | Car | Japan | China | 2023/01/02 | shipping | 3,000 | 100| 13
Toyota| America | Car | Japan | China | 2023/01/02 | shipping | 3,000 | 100| 13
Toyota| America | Car | Japan | China | 2023/01/02 | shipping | 3,000 | 100| 13


Your input is not a CSV. Also, we can't use an image to reproduce your data, please provide a [mre]

Refrain from showing your dataframe as an image.   Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples for best practices related to Pandas questions.

apologies.. have done so

Correct me if I'm wrong, but .dat files don't have any set structure. So why would Pandas have tools for working with them? Maybe you want to ask if this data is in some common format?

Based on the structure of the dat file, it looks like this is a report generated from some raw data, possibly in csv file format.  Do you have access to the base data?

I don't think there are any ready made functions that can read this arbitrary datastructure into a nice table.
First step would be to check where this data comes from. Most likely the original source is in a neat table, and if you can read that (e.g. through some API), your problem disappears.
If not, here is how I would try to transform this data.
# import
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

# paste data
# Pasted from the question
data = """
CAR REPORT                                  AREA 1                                                                                                                                
               Car  Honda              Country  America                        
                  Type  Car                                  
<SNIPPED FOR BREVITY>
   3,000     100     13
   3,000     100     13
   3,000     100     13
"""

Now read the data into a list and clean up a bit
# Read the pasted data into a list, one line at a time
lines = StringIO(data).readlines()
# Strip out trailing and leading whitespace
no_whitespace_lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
clean_lines = [x for x in no_whitespace_lines if x != '']

# Break up the reports, a new report starts when the words "CAR REPORT" appear
reports = []
report = []
for line in clean_lines:
    if line.startswith("CAR REPORT"):
        # Store the existing report before starting anew
        if len(report) > 0:
            reports.append(report)
        # Start a new report
        report = []
        report.append(line)
    else:
        report.append(line)
# The final report never hits a subsequent "CAR REPORT" so store final time here
reports.append(report)

This is "the heart" of the parser and can be improved a lot, especially the metadata parsing. It's now very fragile and breaks if a value (e.g. the country) contains a space. You can look into regex to build a more robust parser.
# Now build a parser for each report
def parser(report: list[str]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Assume that this header is identical.
    # This breaks if there are whitespaces in a value, e.g. 'South Korea'
    metadata = dict(
        area=report[0].split()[3],
        car=report[1].split()[1],
        country=report[1].split()[3],
        vehicle_type=report[2].split()[1],
        built_loc=report[3].split()[2],
        ship_loc=report[3].split()[5],
        date=report[4].split()[1],
        transport=report[4].split()[3],
    )

    columns = report[6].split()

    # Find where the tabular data starts and place that into a dataframe
    mark_counter = 0
    dataset = []
    for line in report:
        if line.startswith("====="):
            mark_counter += 1
            continue
        if mark_counter == 2:
            dataset.append(line.split())

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=dataset, columns=columns)
    for k, v in metadata.items():
        df[k] = v

    return df

Now parse your list of reports and concatenate the various reports into one dataframe:
dfs = []
for report in reports:
    dfs.append(parser(report))
pd.concat(dfs).reset_index()




PPM
Price
Age
area
car
country
vehicle_type
built_loc
ship_loc
date
transport




2,000
100
12
1
Honda
America
Car
Japan
China
2023/01/02
shipping


3,000
100
13
1
Honda
America
Car
Japan
China
2023/01/02
shipping


3,000
100
13
1
Honda
America
Car
Japan
China
2023/01/02
shipping


3,000
100
13
1
Honda
America
Car
Japan
China
2023/01/02
shipping


3,000
100
13
1
Honda
America
Car
Japan
China
2023/01/02
shipping


2,000
100
12
2
Toyota
America
Car
Japan
China
2023/01/02
shipping


3,000
100
13
2
Toyota
America
Car
Japan
China
2023/01/02
shipping


3,000
100
13
2
Toyota
America
Car
Japan
China
2023/01/02
shipping


3,000
100
13
2
Toyota
America
Car
Japan
China
2023/01/02
shipping


3,000
100
13
2
Toyota
America
Car
Japan
China
2023/01/02
shipping



Alternatively, if this is a one off, you could try ChatGPT.
Provide it with your data and "ask" it to transform it into a tabular format with the columns you want. In my brief test the outcome is quite good.

this massively helped me!
